# Viewing the csv file in application locally

Tags: objective-c, ios, csv, directory, document

I am new to iPhone development.I am working on project where i have to create .csv file in application locally and view it within the application itself. I have succeed in creating the .csv file and savig it in document directory.But problem is that i dont know how do i view that .csv excel within the application after creating.Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume u might be saving csv in document directory.U can use UIWebView to display your csv content like this;

```
NSString *filePath = [self documentsDirectoryPath];
filePath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.csv"]; //your saved fileName
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
    [yourWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]]];
}
```

Get document directory path like this:

```
- (NSString *)documentsDirectoryPath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return documentsDirectoryPath;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but i want to view the csv file in excel sheet format.How can i achieve this.